# How much harm can a non-root user cause?

Tags: linux, security

Let's say you add a user to your Linux server, and allow the user to connect over SSH with full command-line access, but do not add him to the list of sudoers.

What sort of security vulnerabilities and damage can this user cause to your server? **Most importantly**, what steps can be done to preemptively prevent such damage?

Comment: Another problem a non-root user can cause is taking up too much RAM or processing power; I haven't posted it as an answer as I still need a solution for how to prevent this type of damage.

Comment: A user can install a compiler and compile a wide range of software, including tools used to exploit the system.

Comment: A non-root user once drove a car into my SAN.  Took out all our servers, even the ones he wasn't a user on!

Comment: @hopelessn00b that's a horrible exploit that people can take advantage of even without a user account.  Clearly you need a moat, with sharks.

Answer (score 1):

### Taking up too much space on the file system

Since non-root users are allowed to write files to their home directory out of the box, it is possible for them to flood that directory with large files.

This will cause problems for other users on the server who no longer have space for their files, and if the file system for the server uses the same partition as the `/home/` directory, it will cause problems for the server as well.

This can be prevented by limiting the maximum size of the home directories for each user to a fixed amount. Several ways how to do this are listed in the following question:

- [AskUbuntu: How can I limit disk space usage for one user?](https://askubuntu.com/q/33328/23496)